# How to add animation to ObjectListView control?

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, objectlistview

Trying to add some simple animation to [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html).  After adding reference to the latest ObjectListView.dll downloaded from sourceforge, am not able to access BrightIdeasSoftware.AnimatedDecoration namespace. Apparently there is no AnimatedDecoration class available in the BrightIdeasSoftware namespace. Do i need to make changes related to project configuration/settings ?

Using Visual Studio 2005 on windows 7.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animated decorations that are part of ObjectListView require .NET 3.5 or later. So, VS 2005 doesn't support them. If you use VS 2008 or later, the `AnimatedDecoration` class will be available.

You should definitely download the whole ObjectListView demo and see how it works.

You can see the original article about animations here: [Animated Eye Candy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71028/Animated-Eye-Candy-for-Programmers)

Comment: before posting this question here i had originally posted the same question in the comments section of Animated Eye Candy link   :-)  Thank you for the quick response on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend upgrading to visual studio 2013 if that is an option for you so you can take advantage of their new application code named Blend, it's built for just such situations where you want to create basic or advanced animations in your project.

Comment: Blend is for WPF. This question is about WinForms.